# can somebody explain what exactly is going on with python functions?

Tags: python, class, oop

what i know in python is i can write something like this

```
blabla = Classname().somefunctions()
```

but in this case both the "np.arange" and "reshape" are functions and it confuses me because  "np.arange" is a function and is treated like a class.   the question is how is this possible??

```
import numpy as np  
a = np.arange(15).reshape(3, 5)
print(a)
```

Comment: `...is treated like a class` - can you explain what you mean by that statement?

Comment: [method chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is an object oriented language, where every variable is an object. `np.arange` [returns](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) `ndarray` object. And then, you could call `reshape` method of `ndarray` object.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(15)

type(a)
Out[148]: numpy.ndarray

a
Out[149]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14])

a = a.reshape(3, 5)

type(a)
Out[151]: numpy.ndarray

a
Out[152]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing this behavior:

```
blabla = Classname().somefunctions()
```

Which is assigning the value returned by calling the method `somefunctions()` located in class `Classname()` to the variable `blabla`

with the chaining of two functions in the numpy module:
The first `a = np.arange(15)` creates and array of size 15, and assigns it to a variable named `a`, and:
the second `a.reshape(3, 5)` that reshapes the array `a` to an array of 3 arrays containing 5 elements each.

```
import numpy as np  
a = np.arange(15)    #-> [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14]
a = a.reshape(3, 5)  #-> [[ 0  1  2  3  4] [ 5  6  7  8  9] [10 11 12 13 14]]
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

[numpy.arange](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) returns an `ndarray` object.

What may have been confusing though is that [numpy.reshape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) is a classmethod that takes an array as an input. However there is an equivalent method [numpy.ndarray.reshape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html#numpy.ndarray.reshape) that is a method available to `ndarray` objects. In your case, it is the latter method that has been used.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `np.arange(15)` returns an instance of a class. Actually everything in python are classes. That's why you can for example do `"HELLO WORLD".lower()`

In this case what the code does is to evaluate `np.(arange)` and after `reshape(3, 5)`

So this will be the equivalent:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(15)
a = a.reshape(3, 5)
print(a)
```